# Compare values in an object to the ones of a parameter

Tags: java

I'm working on a class for a lab I'm in, and I'm required to implement this functionality:

```
// 6. ***** Write this method *****
// method name:  equals
// return value: boolean
// parameter:    Airport object
// function:     returns true if airportCode
//                and gates in this object
//                are equal to those in the parameter object;
//               returns false otherwise
```

Honestly speaking, this isn't for a grade but for my understanding. I simply don't know how to compare the current object to the parameter. What is the solution to this?

Comment: What you have tried so far. Is this your homework ? Sorry.

Comment: First try coding something by yourself before you ask something

Comment: Yeah, like I haven't been trying. It's just what I've tried is completely wrong. Also no, not homework. Just a lab to help my understanding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what it's meant:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Airport) {
            if(this.airportCode.equals(((Airport) obj).getAirportCode())) {
                String[] gs = ((Airport) obj).getGates();
                Arrays.sort(gates);
                Arrays.sort(gs);
                //Compare gates, if not equal, return false, else true
                return gatesAreEqual;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you're supposed to override the `equals` method of the `Object` class.

As there is no info on whether the gates are saved as an array, a `List`/`Set` (`Collection`) or as an object of a different `class` altogether, all three solutions are provided.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(other == null)
        return false;               // Nothing is equal to null, other than null (in which case 
                                    // this method would not be callable)
    if(this == other)
        return true;                // They are already the same reference
    if(!(other instanceof Airport))
        return false;               // An Airport can not be considered equal to a non-Airport object

    Airport port = (Airport) other; // This cast is now safe, as other must 
                                    // be of type Airport

    // Until next END, this can be removed if airportCode can never be null
    if(airportCode == null) {
        if(port.airportCode != null)
            return false;           // "Mine is null, theirs is not."
    }
    // END
    if(!port.airportCode.equals(airportCode))
        return false;               // "Their code is different from our."



    // IF gates is an array, note that this distorts any ordering that is non-comformant 
    // with the natural order imposed by the compareTo-method

    Object[] otherGates = port.gates;
    Arrays.sort(gates);             // Sort our gates
    Arrays.sort(otherGates);        // Sort their gates
    return Arrays.equals(gates, otherGates); // This may need overwriting the equals 
                                             // method of the gates, if it isn't a String


    // IF gates is a collection, again, may distort orderings

    List<?> otherGates = port.gates;         // Replace the ? with the type
    Comparator<?> c = null;                  // Again, replace the ?. Assign an implementation of Comparator
                                             // if ? does not implement Comparable on its own

    gates.sort(c);                           // Sort our gates
    otherGates.sort(c);                      // Sort their gates
    return gates.equals(otherGates);         // This may need overwriting the equals 
                                             // method of the gates, if it isn't a String


    // Now at last, if the gates are an object all of their own
    Gates otherGates = port.gates;
    return gates.equals(otherGates);         // Needs an overwriting of equals in class Gates
}
```

Note that this can be made a lot more concise, but it is displayed this way to be easier to understand and due to the information given being incomplete.